# Testing Dockerfile which runs on non root user using Serverspec

Tags: docker, rspec, dockerfile, sudo, serverspec

I have a Dockerfile which spins up Jenkins slave nodes using the Jenkins Swarm plugin. I have a non-root user "jenkins" setup in this image. There is nvm setup for the jenkins user. I am trying to test this Docker image using serverspec and I can't seem to find a way to run a command as a non-root user in the server spec file.

This confirms that user jenkins is installed:

```
  describe user('jenkins') do
    it { should exist }
    it { should belong_to_primary_group 'jenkins' }
  end
```

But I can't seem to make this work:

```
  describe command('whoami') do
    let(:sudo_options) { '-u jenkins -i' }
    its(:stdout) { should match 'jenkins' }
  end
```

I even tried something like this:

```
  describe command('sudo -u jenkins nvm --version') do
    its(:stdout) { should match(/0.33.0/) }
  end
```

Looking for help in making this work with serverspec. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @BMW When I do the "whoami" I am expecting "jenkins" but I get back root. And in nvm --version I expect "0.33.0" but I get back ""

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me. If anyone reading this post has a better way of doing this please do let me know.

```
  describe command("node --version") do
    its(:stdout) { should match(/5.10.0/) }
  end

  describe command("su - jenkins -c 'node --version'") do
    its(:stdout) { should match(/6.9.5/) }
  end

  describe command("su - jenkins -c 'nvm --version'") do
    its(:stdout) { should match(/0.33.0/) }
  end

  describe command("su - jenkins -c 'nvm use 4.7.3'") do
    its(:stdout) { should match(/4.7.3/) }
  end
```